# socket.io connection event not working

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am new to nodejs and express and trying the socket.io just a simple chat application.
Its very simple code everything is just fine but there is no event fired logs on the node console. Connection event code is not working.
Furthermore socket.io.js file in browser side giving 200 ok.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');    

var app = express();    
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
        err.status = 404;
        next(err);
    });

    /// error handlers

    // development error handler
    // will print stacktraces
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
        app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
            res.status(err.status || 500);
            res.render('error', {
                message: err.message,
                error: err
            });
        });
    }

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: {}
        });
    });

        var http  = require('http');

    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

    var server = http.createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket){  
      console.log('a user connected');  ///***this is not working
      socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected'); 
      });
    });
    module.exports = app;
```

Client side code  using jade templating

```
extends layout  
block content
    h1 Socket.io
    ul#messages
    form(action='')
        input#m(autocomplete='off')
        button Send
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    script(type="text/javascript")
        var socket = io();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably could answer this question better if you provide the client side code; however you can find some simple examples of connecting with socket.ok here https://github.com/dcorns/exploreSocketIO At a minimum you need   or equivalent method on the client as it will initiate the handshake. If follow the link all should become clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help... It was problem with jade because when i opened source it was showing <var> socket = io(); </var>
i created another file and included var socket = io(); like script(type='text/javascript', src='../javascripts/socks.js')

Answer (score 0):

Have you used client side code?
 a sample code may look like this.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

plz use like this:

```
  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){  
        console.log('a user connected');  
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
           console.log('user disconnected'); 
        });
  });
```

Comment: you have to require var io=require('io'); after installation of io module of node.js. and this is the best way to use express io in node.js. if you are working with socket programming in node.js io will be the great thing to use. just use this. this will sure work fine..